# Multiple inputs and separated outputs with parcel

Tags: parceljs

Until recently, I worked with one page and builded it with `parcel build src/pages/colors-and-type/colors-and-type.pug -d docs --public-url ./`.

But now I have several pages, respectively, several entry points. In addition to that, I saw the confusion that comes up when I output everything to /docs/(added screenshot), how can I divide everything into folders(fonts separately, pages and styles also separately)?

Thanks in advance for help!

[image: files confusion]